# Email Repeats Classification: Python function and conditional statement error

Tags: python, function

I have written a python function to check whether a mail is a repeat or fresh on the basis of difference in dates of last mail and current mail from a customer.

'Days_Difference' contains numeric values like 0, 15 along with 'None'

Function is defined as follows:

```
def Status(df['Days_Difference']):
    if(df['Days_Difference'] < 30):
         return 'repeat'
    elif(df['Days_Difference'] > 30):
         return 'fresh'
    else:
         return 'not in list'
```

I am getting error:

> '<' not supported in between 'str' and 'int' types

I attempted `df['Days_Difference'] = int(df['Days_Difference'])` but it didn't work out.

I also attempted `df['Days_Difference'] = pd.numeric(df['Days_Difference'])` but it also does not work out.

I'm looking for a solution!

Answer (score 1):

(I'm making the assumption that `df` is a pandas dataframe)

You found the problem yourself.

You said `df['a']` contains integers and `'None'`. `'None'` is a string, thus it can not be compared with an integer. This is easily reproducible:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 'None', 3, 4, 5]})

if df['a'] < 3:
    pass

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

There is another problem. Even if `df['a']` were to contain only integers this code would not have worked:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

if df['a'] < 3:
    pass

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

This is because `df['a'] < 3` returns a mask of the indexes where the values in `a` fulfills the condition `< 3`:

```
print((df['a'] < 3).tolist())

# [True, True, False, False, False]
```

Calling `bool` on that (which is what `if` is essentially doing) does not make any sense. Is `[True, True, False, False, False]` true? is it false? It is ambiguous just like the error says.

You'll need to rethink the logic of this function and what you actually want it to return in what condition.